# Model Extensions in BreezeJS from a RequireJS Module

Tags: requirejs, breeze

I often extend my Entities in BreezeJS using the below syntax:

```
var Employee = function () {
this.FirstName = ko.observable(""); // default FirstName
this.LastName = ko.observable("");  // default LastName
this.fullName = ko.computed(
        function () {
            return this.FirstName() + " " + this.LastName();
        }, this);
```

};

```
manager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("Employee", Employee);
```

When I do this inline (in the same script) it works as expected. When I move the Employee definition to it's own Require.JS module, the prototype changes from

```
{}
```

to

```
{ __moduleId__ : 'Employee' }
```

BreezeJS chokes on this, and gives a :

```
TypeError: cannot call "bind" of undefined.
```

I've created a bandaid fix by this by assigning Employee.prototype = {} before the registration of the constructor, but I feel this isn't the best approach.

Is it possible to override Require.JS's modification of the module's prototype, or is it possible to make Breeze.JS play nicely with this extra bit of code?

Alternatively, I've considered nesting my object so I'd do something like:

```
manager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("Employee", Employee.modelCtor);
```

Though that also feels clumsy to me. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your entity on initialization.  Instead of using the constructor, use the initializer -

```
manager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("Employee", Employee.modelCtor, empInitializer);

function empInitializer(employee) {
    employee.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        var ln = employee.lastName();
        var fn = employee.firstName();
        return fn + ' ' + ln;
    });
}
```

Comment: that causes the same issue. It's not the constructor or the initializer themselves, but rather the fact that Require attaches additional data to their prototypes when it resolves the corresponding module.

Comment: In this case, the module containing the function empInitializer would return with empInitializer.prototype equaling { __moduleId__ : 'Employee'}. I'm searching for a way to make breeze accept that, or to make Require not do it in the first place.   I'll keep googlin'

Comment: ?  Where are you creating your entity manager?  Just put the initializer there and the fullName property is common property of employees

Comment: I'm using Require.JS. Are you familiar with it? The initializer/constructor would be contained in a module which is loaded from another file. Require.JS is "contaminating" the prototype, which Breeze doesn't seem to like. Your approach would work if it wasn't for the Require.JS part.

Comment: I am very familiar with it and I am using it in the project that I referenced above where I copied and pasted my code out of.  It works fine

Comment: You're correct. It does indeed work in a slimmed version of my project. I appear to have another bug besides the one in the question. Many thanks kind sir!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same symptoms with a very similar example, in the end fixed it by deleting the `__moduleId__` property which was tripping Breeze up. As below:

```
// workspace.js
define(['durandal/system', 'ko'], function (system, ko) {

    return function() {
        this.myBreezeEntityProperty = ko.observableArray();

        // Delete the __moduleId__ property so breeze works
        delete this.constructor.prototype.__moduleId__;
    };
});

// domain.js    
define(['./workspace', ...], function(Workspace, ...) {
    breezemetadatastore.registerEntityTypeCtor("Workspace", Workspace)
});
```

Comment: I'll try this out Rich.